# Loading rails assets after page had loaded using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application that uses Rails templating and I usually return my data via the controller actions with @profile.

However, I have a page that I don't want to increase the page load for, so instead of returning @related_profiles I am loading the page and using jQuery to make a call to another API to download @related_profiles.

View:

```
<header class="media">
  <figure class="media-left">
    <%= image_tag('icon-temp_profile.png', :alt => 'Avatar', :class => 'u-img', :height => '40',  :id => 'other-profile-photo-3') %>
  </figure>

  <div class="media-body">
    <strong class="mr2" id="other-profile-name-3">NAME</strong> <span class="u-inlineBlock"></span>
    <span class="u-block  u-textSmall  u-textMuted" id="other-profile-school-3">
      SCHOOL
    </span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Now, I am using jQuery to update some related profile fields such as name, school etc. However, I want to replace the default profile image but due to that image being served from S3, I don't know it's URL.

I have the file name, but not the URL and since the page is already loaded, I can't do:

```
someAssetPath = "<%= asset_path('#{other_profile.profile_picture_file_name}') %>"
$('#other-profile-photo-3').attr( "src" , someAssetPath )
```

Controller:

```
def endorsements
  other_profiles = OtherProfileServices::SuggestedProfilesFetcher.fetch(current_user.id)

  return render json: other_profiles
end
```

What is the best solution here? Can I somehow get the asset_path and pass it in? Should I swap to using a templating library? Is so which one is most lightweight?

Comment: Show the controller action that returns the @related_profiles and, if you have one, the view you render there.

Comment: @arieljuod added the controller, the view is shown above. I am using jquery to swap out values like Name... could be done better?